# Problem with deploying MERN stack app to GAE Standard Env

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, deployment, mern

We're trying to deploy our MERN stack app to Google's App Engine. Before we were using *flex environment*, but to enable redirecting to **https every time**, we switched to *Standard env*. After this change, we encountered a few problems, such as: sometimes our main ('/') page doesn't load, for some users the website remains unsecured and:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '<'
```

What could be the solution to fix all of these problems?

Below I'm attaching code snippets.

Our code structure looks like:

- client

  | - build

  | - src

  | - package.json

  | - ...
- routes/api
- package.json
- server.js
- app.yaml
- ...

client/package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "proxy": "http://localhost:5000",
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": "react-app"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
```

Package.json:

```
"scripts": {
"client-install": "npm install --prefix client",
"start": "node server.js",
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"client": "npm start --prefix client",
"dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\"",
"heroku-postbuild": "NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client",
"test": "jest"
},
```

App.Yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs12

automatic_scaling:
  max_instances: 2

resources:
  cpu: .5
  memory_gb: 0.5
  disk_size_gb: 10

handlers:
  - url: /.*
    secure: always
    redirect_http_response_code: 301
    script: auto

  - url: /
    static_files: client/build/index.html
    upload: client/build/index.html
    secure: always

  - url: /
    static_dir: client/build
    secure: always
```

In our server.js we have:

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
  console.log('production')
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build')))
  app.get('/*', (req, res) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '/client/build/index.html'))
  })
}

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`))
```

Comment: It looks like you're missing the `app.listen()`. So you app won't respond to anything that is sent to port 5000.

Comment: I skipped that part, as this was not causing any problems. Updated the question to contain the app.listen()

Comment: So this issue is only affecting some users and not all of them?